# How to make a 3D plot using polar coordinates?

Tags: plotting

From the beginning: I have function $u(r)$ and radial symmetry in system. Also I've got results as data array ${u_i(r_i)}$. And I want to plot it as $u(x,y)$. Due to radial symmetry its gonna be like $x=r \cos(\varphi), y=r \sin(\varphi)$  In other words I have function profile and want to "integrate" it over $2\pi\,\mathrm d\varphi$. Like this for [Gaussian](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3e/Gaussian_2d.svg)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Use `RevolutionPlot3D[]` instead.

Comment: Have you looked at [`ParametricPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot3D.html)?  I believe it can be applied.

Comment: All this works if I have a rule for my U(r) -> U(x,y). But I have to assign a numerical value from list of already obtained values to new rule for (x,y) to build concentric circles. Maybe I'm missing something.I'm novice in mathematica, all my knowledges based on F1 help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option would be to use `RevolutionPlot3D`.

```
u = Table[Sin[2 \[Pi]*r], {r, 0, 1, 0.1}]; (*u is a dummy u[r]*)
f = ListInterpolation[u, {0, 1}]; (*Create an interpolating function over the range {0,1}*)
(*Plot it over the domain.*)
RevolutionPlot3D[f[r], {r, #1, #2}] & @@@ f["Domain"]
```

[image]

You could also generate the points yourself and use `ListPointPlot3D`

```
u = Table[{r, Sin[2 \[Pi]*r]}, {r, 0, 1, 0.1}];(*table of {r,u[r]}*)
xyz = Flatten[Table[{#1*Cos[\[Theta]], #1*Sin[\[Theta]], #2} & @@@ u, {\[Theta],0, 2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]/100} ], 1];
ListPointPlot3D[
 xyz
 , Filling -> Axis
 ]
```

[image]