# How to make a 3D plot using polar coordinates radius and angle dependence

Tags: plotting, plot-themes

I want to create a polar plot like this:

[image]

Which can not be made with the `RevolutionPlot3D` comand like [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83867/how-to-make-a-3d-plot-using-polar-coordinates), it is because my function is dependent of the radius `r` and the angle `Theta`. I already tried with this code:

```
b = 0.042
m = 1
a = 0.1075
Gamma1 = 27.6561421691630044961129897274076938629150390625`50.
B1 = 10.8721158771190697933661795104853808879852294921875`50.
C1 = 1.0083854268623009264871370760374702513217926025390625`50.
D1 = 12.755787693798620097140883444808423519134521484375`50.
ParametricPlot3D[{(BesselJ[m, Gamma1*r] + 
      B1*BesselY[m, Gamma1*r] + C1*BesselI[m,Gamma1*r] + 
      D1*BesselK[m,Gamma1*r])*
    (Sin[m*Theta]+Cos[m*Theta])}, {Theta, 0, 2*Pi}, {r, b, a}]
```

I do not know why my code does not work.

Comment: Your function should be a vector-valued function to use `ParameticPlot3D`.

Comment: @L.Yu What do you mean by vector-valued function?.

Comment: maybe `ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[ Theta], 
  r  Sin[Theta], (BesselJ[m, Gamma1*r] + B1*BesselY[m, Gamma1*r] + 
     C1*BesselI[m, Gamma1*r] + 
     D1*BesselK[m, Gamma1*r])*(Sin[m*Theta] + Cos[m*Theta])}, {Theta, 
  0, 2*Pi}, {r, b, a}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]`?

Comment: Comment: an interesting surface, which appears to be topologically a cylinder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ParametricPlot3D[{r Sin[Theta], r Cos[Theta],
   (BesselJ[m, Gamma1 r] + B1 BesselY[m, Gamma1 r] + 
     C1 BesselI[m, Gamma1 r] + D1 BesselK[m, Gamma1 r])*(Sin[m Theta] + Cos[m Theta])}, 
 {Theta, 0, 2 Pi}, {r, b, a}, Mesh -> {Range[0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/20], 10}, 
 PlotStyle -> None, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, BoxRatios -> 1, 
 BoundaryStyle -> Black]
```

[image]